# remove last entered character when typeahead doesnt have any results

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

Hi I am using ng bootstrap typeahead. This is my search function:

```
search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
    text$.pipe(
      debounceTime(200),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      map(term => term.length < 2 ? []
        : states.filter(v => v.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1).slice(0, 10))
    )
```

I want to disallow entering into the input text that is not part of my dropdown option e.g if the options of the dropdown are : 
one, two, three
if the user is trying to type k the k character will be removed because no matching dropdown options were found...

Answer (score 1):

just store in a variable the last "term" that give you reult. In a tap, if result.length<0 recover this value

```
  public model: any;
  public lastOk:any;

  search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
    text$.pipe(
      debounceTime(200),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      map((term) => 
      {
        const result=states.filter(v => v.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1)
                 .slice(0, 10);
        if (result.length)
          this.lastOk=term
        return result;
      }),
      tap((res)=>{
        if (res.length<=0)
        this.model=this.lastOk
      })
    )
```

You can see in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rtsdjv?file=app%2Ftypeahead-basic.ts)

NOTE: If you don't remove the condition term.length < 2 the user can type any word that not match with anything

Comment: thanks but the charachter is deleted with a delay.. any solution to that? I want to not let the user press any input if the previous typing doesnt match...